# Passing parameter into “Row_Number”

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, row-number

I am getting the following **`syntax error`** with the following query when i try to parameterize column name.   **`Incorrect syntax near '@SortBy'.`**

I was able to make it work using a dynamic SQL but the problem is **`Entity Framework`**  won't create complex types for **`SPs with exec`**.

Is there a way/work around  to make this query work other than dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE
        @MLSIdList varchar(max),
    @SortBy varchar(max),
    @LowRow int,
    @HighRow int

SET @MLSIdList = '12-632393,12-73464,12-39834,12-78237'
SET @SortBy = 'ORDER BY a.mlsnum, a.yb, a.RatePlugMID  '
SET @LowRow = 11
SET @HighRow = 23


SELECT a.mlsId , a.ADDRESS, a.APN , a.RatePlugMID,a.hod , a.yb , a.UNUM ,
       a.CHANGETYPE , a.CITY , a.County,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( @SortBy ) AS RowNumber,
FROM mls_unified_svo_tbl a (nolock) 
WHERE a.MLSNUM IN ( @MLSIdList )
```

Comment: not it you want to pass `ORDER BY` of your `OVER` clause dynamically.

Comment: i want to pass ORDER BY of OVER caluse as a paremeter

Comment: "@SortBy varchar(max) change into @SortBy Nvarchar(max)"